# prepareForInterfaceBuilder doesn't update my storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I've created a simple day calendar view and I'd like to see it rendering live on my storyboard, but I've managed to show only the code in `-drawRect:`.
Running on the simulator I get this image, that represents the correct final result, but in storyboard I get this.
[image] 
On storyboard I get this
[image]

The `CalendarDayView` is a subclass of a another view whose purpose is to load a nib with a specific name and add it a as a subview. `CalendarDayView` is tagged as IB_DESIGNABLE.
It is added as a subview directly on the storyboard.

To show also the label inside the `CalendarDayView` in the `-prepareForInterfaceBuilder` method I've written some placeholder text.

```
- (void) prepareForInterfaceBuilder {
    [super prepareForInterfaceBuilder];
    self.yearLabel.text = @"2015";
    self.monthLabel.text = @"FEBRUARY";
    self.dayLabel.text = @"28";
}
```

Draw rect is shown fine

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:20];
    [APP_CALENDAR_VIEW_COLOR setFill];
    [path fill];
}
```

How can I achieve to show labels while editing my storyboard? even if I show the preview nothing is shown.